# Combining CustomBusinessDay and BusinessHour Classes in Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I've recently started using Pandas and found the [CustomBusinessDay](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental)  and [BusinessHour](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#business-hour) class to be very useful for doing calendar-math while accounting for specific business rules. However, I was wondering if was possible to combine them to calculate timedeltas that respect both classes.

For example, I would like to add n business hours to a start time and have it skip both the "off-hours" defined by the BusinessHour class and as well as all hours in "off-days" defined in the CustomBusinessDay class.

Does anyone with more experience with this library know if this can be easily accomplished or, if not, have a suggestion for how this functionality might be encapsulated in another class?

Comment: @WoodChopper Can you elaborate? I linked to that doc page in my post, but I do not see anywhere that it indicates how the two classes can be used together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from version 0.18.1, you can use [`CustomBusinessHour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#custom-business-hour):

> The CustomBusinessHour is a mixture of BusinessHour and
>   CustomBusinessDay which allows you to specify arbitrary holidays. For
>   details, see [Custom Business Hour](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/timeseries.html#timeseries-custombusinesshour) ([GH11514](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11514))
>
> ```
> In [1]: from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessHour
>
> In [2]: from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
>
> In [3]: bhour_us = CustomBusinessHour(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
> Friday before MLK Day
>
> In [4]: dt = datetime(2014, 1, 17, 15)
>
> In [5]: dt + bhour_us
> Out[5]: Timestamp('2014-01-17 16:00:00')
> Tuesday after MLK Day (Monday is skipped because it’s a holiday)
>
> In [6]: dt + bhour_us * 2
> Out[6]: Timestamp('2014-01-21 09:00:00')
> ```

An example that I am using is

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessHour
from pandas.tseries.holiday import Holiday, AbstractHolidayCalendar

class MyCalendar(AbstractHolidayCalendar):
    rules = [Holiday('my birthday', month=6, day=6)]

cbh = CustomBusinessHour(2, start='10:00', end='16:00', calendar=MyCalendar())

pd.date_range('20170602', periods=20, freq=cbh)

Out: 
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-02 10:00:00', '2017-06-02 12:00:00',
               '2017-06-02 14:00:00', '2017-06-05 10:00:00',
               '2017-06-05 12:00:00', '2017-06-05 14:00:00',
               '2017-06-07 10:00:00', '2017-06-07 12:00:00',
               '2017-06-07 14:00:00', '2017-06-08 10:00:00',
               '2017-06-08 12:00:00', '2017-06-08 14:00:00',
               '2017-06-09 10:00:00', '2017-06-09 12:00:00',
               '2017-06-09 14:00:00', '2017-06-12 10:00:00',
               '2017-06-12 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='2CBH')
```